# Android application to transmit particular radio frequency

Tags: android

Is it possible to built an app for android smart phone that can send particular frequency? If yes than what could be the range of frequency?

Answer (score 0):

No, because most Android devices do not have software-defined radio (SDR). You are welcome to build your own hardware that does, or find an Android-powered SDR and see what sorts of SDK it might offer.